# Pattern formation stimulation for gierer-meinhardt system using MatLab

Tags: matlab, design-patterns

I am studying the Gierer-Meinhardt reaction-diffusion system and I have tried to code up the model in order to produce some patterns, like spots or stripes. I have calculated the Turing instability space and used values from that space to use as an input, but after a couple of seconds the screen goes blank! So could be wrong maths, or could be wrong code, this is for my degree and any help would be amazing!

```matlab
function gierermeinhardt(a, b) % Diffusion rates
D=2; % Size of grid width = 128; % 5,000 simulation seconds with 4 steps per simulated second
dt = .25;
stoptime = 3000;
[t, u, v] = initial_conditions(width);
axes('Position',[0 0 1 1]) axis off   % Add a scaled-color image
hi = image(v);
set(hi,'CDataMapping','scaled');
targetframerate = 6; %24;
frametime = 1/(24*60*60*targetframerate);
nextframe = now + frametime;
tic nframes = 1;
while t<stoptime
    ut = u + (a - b*u + u.^2./v  + my_laplacian(u))*dt;
    vt = v + (u.^2 - v + D.*my_laplacian(v))*dt;
    u = ut;
    v = vt;
    set(hi,'CData',v);
    t = t+dt;
    ht.String = ['Time = ' num2str(t)];
    if now > nextframe
        drawnow
        nextframe = now + frametime;
    end
    nframes = nframes+1;
end delta = toc;
disp([num2str(nframes) ' frames in ' num2str(delta) ' seconds']);
function out = my_laplacian(in)
out = -in ...       + .20*(circshift(in,[ 1, 0]) + circshift(in,[-1, 0])  ...       +      circshift(in,[ 0, 1]) + circshift(in,[ 0,-1])) ...       + .05*(circshift(in,[ 1, 1]) + circshift(in,[-1, 1])  ...       +      circshift(in,[-1,-1]) + circshift(in,[ 1,-1]));
function [t, u, v] = initial_conditions(n)
t = 0; % Initialize A to one
v = ones(n); % Initialize B to zero which a clump of ones
u = zeros(n);
u(51:60 ,51:70) = 1;
u(61:80,71:80) = 1;
```

Comment: Please start [with formatting your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program under Octave, so there may be a difference, but I think
I understand what the problem is.

First of all, your title, ht.String, does not seem to go anywhere in the
figure (and as we'll see later, this matters).  I changed it into

```
s = text(40,10, 'Time = 0');
```

And also:

```
if now > nextframe
    set(s,'string', ['Time = ',num2str(t),' 1+', num2str(min(min(v))-1),' <= v <= 1+',num2str(max(max(v))-1)])
    drawnow
    nextframe = now + frametime;
end
```

The movie played depends on the values for a and b, and I chose `a=1; b=2`.
What I get then, is that the values of v become all equal to `1+2.2e-16`
after `t=145`.  This means that the entire figure has only one color.
And, in absence of a title, this is a 'blank screen'.